# get location update every 1 hour

Tags: android

I want to get location update after every 1 hour, I don't want to be concern with distance, only after every 1 hour I should got current location.
My code is

```
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 3600000, 0, listener);
```

so if I pass o as distance so will it give me updation after 1 hour or not

Answer (score 1):

The `minDistance` parameter (the one you put `0` in) is, as name states, the minimum difference in location that qualifies for being posted as an update. If you put zero there, you'll get notification about any location change, regardless of the distance traveled.